# Using Esprima to find necessary child expressions of "for", "var", "function", etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

I'm trying to automatically generate the correct punctuation for each expression in Javascript.

**Example:**

I'd like to take the string `"for"`

and return `["init", "test", "update", "body"]`

from which I could generate something like: `["(", ")",  "{", "}"]`.

That is, I need all the standard characters required for a correct expression.

**What I know:**

I know Esprima can generate the AST for **correct** javascript code. Each node of the generated node has a key for each of its child nodes. If I could find the node that (for example) `"for"` generates in the AST, and the keys associated to that node type, then I would be done.

I think the answer is somewhere in the Esprima source, but I'm not sure where to look.

**Question:**

How can I find the AST node that (for example) `"for"` would generate in a correct expression, and how can I find that node's children?

Cheers, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you're asking how to find a particular node by key/value in a nested structure?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't as clear as I should be: suppose I only have the string "for", I'd like to know what nodes that requires to be a correct expression. In the case of "for", the correct answer would be 'init', 'test', 'update' and 'body'. Then I could infer the correct punctuation.

Comment: Oh, got it. You basically want to complete the production for a given terminal, or at least want to know which Esprima nodes would be required. So I guess you're wondering if Esprima has something built in that'll do that?

Comment: Precisely; I'm trying not to resort to manually creating a list of them myself!

Comment: Makes sense. I don't know the answer, but keep in mind that there can be multiple options. Given `for`, it could be a `for` statement, `for-in` statement or a `for-of` statement.

Comment: Can you not just parse e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {}` and inspect the AST node? You can also simply hardcode the values based on the estree spec: https://github.com/estree/estree. Or have a look at ast-types: https://github.com/benjamn/ast-types .